# Where is the source code for Python itertools.islice?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Where is the source code for Python itertools.islice?

I found [itertoolsmodule.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c?view=markup), but can't find the function itertools.islice (maybe it's there, but I don't know much about C code).

I would like to understand what happens when I do:

```
itertools.islice(spamreader, rowStart, rowFinish+1)
```

Comment: Looks like it's right there starting around line 1115 or so

Comment: Look at line 1252 (constructor at 1118).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at the old SVN repository; Python has since moved to mercurial. I'd look at he [2.7 version of `itertoolsmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0866382064f/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c); the source has an [`islice` *object*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0866382064f/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1126).

When you call `itertools.islice()` you create a new instance of that object, so `islice_new` is called.

With 3 arguments, `next` in the C struct is set to `int(rowStart)`, `stop` to `int(rowFinish+1)`. `step` is left as `None`, `it` is set to `iter(spamreader)`. Most importantly, `cnt` is set to `0`. Then the object is returned.

All the iteration work is done in `islice_next()`, where `it` is iterated over according to the next, stop and step values.

`cnt` is incremented and `next(it)` is called as needed to advance the object until `cnt` is equal or greater to `next`; after that, for each call to `islice_next()` an item is yielded while `cnt` and `next` are incremented until `stop` is reached.